# TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y' in line 22

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class base:
    def __init__(self,width,length,x,y):
        self.__width=width
        self.__length=length
        self.__x=x
        self.__y=y

    def area(self):
        return self.__width*self.__length

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*(self.__width+self.__length)

    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    def y(self):
        return self.__y

class circle(base):
    def __init__(self,radius,x,y):
      super(circle,self).__init__(x,y)
      self.radius=radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi*pow(self.radius,2)

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2*math.pi*self.radius

class rectangle(base):
    def __init__(self,width,length,x,y):
      super(rectangle,self).__init__(width,length,x,y)

# Test function: 

cir=circle(3,1,2)
cir.area()
```

Comment: What is unclear from the error message? `super(circle,self).__init__(x,y)` - what about the other two parameters to `base`?

Comment: Why are `width` and `length` defined in `base.__init__` in the first place? Circles don't use them, only rectangles.

Comment: as a side note: you should not worry about encapsulating attributes in Python - it is hard to do because it is unnatural to the language - just use `self.x`and `self.y` as attributes  - if you ever need to guard access to them (like, accepting only numbers), you can do so by using "properties" and not changing any client code.

Comment: @Anugrah Singh change `__init__` in base class like this `__init__(self,width = None, length = None, x = None, y = None)`

Answer (score 0):

You should only define data intended for *all* subclasses inheriting from the base. `width` and `length` are not universally applicable.

Following `super` best practices, `__init__` should always call `super().__init__`, and keyword arguments should be used to ensure that any unrecognized arguments are passed up the inheritance chain.

It is usually sufficient to use `_`-prefixed names for private attributes, rather than the `__`-prefixed names subject to name wrangling. It may also be simpler to use them directly; you can always replace them with properties later if it becomes necessary.

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    # Essentially an abstract method
    def area(self):
        pass

    # Essentially an abstract method
    def perimeter(self):
        pass

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
```

Each subclass then overrides `area` and `perimeter`, and can add shape-specific parameters to `__init__` as needed.

```
class Circle(Base):
    def __init__(self, radius, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * pow(self.radius, 2)

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius


class Rectangle(Base):
    def __init__(self, width, length, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.width = width
      self.length = length

    def area(self):
        return self.width * self.length

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.width + self.length)



# Test function: 

cir = Circle(radius=3, x=1, y=2)
cir.area()
```